# Lower bound for the maximum level of ownership for recursive_mutex?

Tags: c++, pthreads, language-lawyer, recursive-mutex

Quoting [[thread.mutex.recursive]](http://eel.is/c++draft/thread.mutex.recursive#3):

> A thread that owns a `recursive_mutex` object may acquire additional levels of ownership by calling `lock()` or `try_lock()` on that object. It is unspecified how many levels of ownership may be acquired by a single thread. If a thread has already acquired the maximum level of ownership for a `recursive_mutex` object, additional calls to `try_lock()` shall fail, and additional calls to `lock()` shall throw an exception of type `system_error`.

Is there a lower bound greater than 1 for the "*maximum level of ownership*"? What about recursive pthread mutexes?

Comment: It's [unspecified](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior) (as in, the standard doesn't mandate any particular value, and implementations don't have to document this).

Comment: That being said, it's basically about a reference counter, and there doesn't seem much reason (in most situations) for that to not be at least a 32bit int. So, for all intents and purposes, I'd consider that limit higher than you could ever practically need.

Comment: Great question though. The fact that it's not given a lower bound is probably a defect in the standard.

Answer (score 0):

There is no lower limit specified in the standard.  This is probably deliberate.

Older standards (C I think) did use to provide lower limits for things like this.  The result was that people wrote coding standards which said you couldn't use more than these lower limits.  For example: It was (and I think still is) implementation defined how many characters of an external symbol were significant when comparing for equality.  So `a_very_very_long_name_indeed_with_extra_padding` and `a_very_very_long_name_indeed_with_extra_paddingX` might be treated as the same symbol.  The minimum length was specified as 8, and coding standards were written specifying "maximum length of a external symbol is eight characters".

On the plausible lower bound for this value:  I can easily imagine that the count might be bit-packed into some other field so that the whole thing can be updated atomically with a suitable instruction.  As such, it might be a good deal less than 32 bits.  (It only really needs to be large enough for the maximum call stack depths, so in a constrained environment, 31 might be good enough.)